# How do I change the representation while storing a sparse matrix in python?

Tags: python, storage, sparse-matrix

The sparse matrix representation is of the form:

```
          (i,j)       value
```

I want to store these values to a text file in 3 columns namely:

```
         i            j               value
```

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: The representation is a dict with a pair `(i, j)` as key and `value` as value? Or is it just another textfile? How much code do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

If your sparse matrix is stored in a dictionary called dict then you can use:

```
f = open('output.txt', 'w')
for (i, j), value in dict.items():
    f.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (i, j, value))
```

This will output the data as a tab-delimited text file.

Comment: The default mode of `open` is `'r'`, so you have to change your first line to `f = open('output.txt', 'w')`